# Get list of items to publish from a sitecore content package / update package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am working on building an [open source continuous deployment tool](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship) for Sitecore. (Auto install content packages as part of an automated deployment)

The next feature I am trying to implement is to publish any changes from a content package. I have the code for publishing a list of items, but I need to get a list of the items that need publishing from the changes in a content package. It is unrealistic to publish a whole site for some of our clients (a full site publish in all languages takes days).

Can you recommend the best way to do this programmatically? I started looking in the `Sitecore.Update.Wizard` namespace for clues, but couldn't see anything obvious.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like `Publish(itemList)` in Sitecore. There are options for publishing single item (optionally with descendants) or the whole site. Looks like you'll need to iterate over the items from the package and Publish them one by one

Comment: Yes, I know You have to publish items individually. I have the code written for that already. What I need is a way to find what items to publish, programatically.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Sitecore's event handlers](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx). What you will want to do is create your own event that will be raised when an item is installed, and have it pass the item or the ID of the item that was installed as an argument to event handlers.

To attach the event, take a look at the `Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller` namespace, as well as others under the `Sitecore.Install` (in `Sitecore.Kernel`).

The next thing that you will want to do is create an event handler to be called when your new event is raised. This event handler should grab the Item/Item ID from the arguments and should then publish it (be sure to first verify that the item does, in fact, exist - item successfully installed).

All that is left is to put your "publish-item" code in the body of the new event handler.